# Ignore words beginning with a hashtag or mention

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

Please forgive me for my noobness but I am having trouble building a pattern to ignore words beginning with a hashtag # or a mention symbol @. I know that to select words beginning with hashtags I can do #(\w+) and to select words beginning with mentions I can do @(\w+).

I tried doing something like this (?!@(\w+)) to ignore the mentions and this (?!#(\w+)) to ignore hashtags but no luck. I'll keep trying and searching any help is appreciated.

I want to create a pattern that: !(hashtags) AND !(mentions)
Or a pattern that selects only words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *words = [[text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
for (NSString *word in words)
{
    NSString *firstCharacter = [word substringToIndex:1];
    if ([firstCharacter isEqual:@"#"] || [firstCharacter isEqual:@"@"])
    {
        // remove the word from the array here or whatever
        [words removeObject:word];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I modified a little bit, but that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me based on the answer provided by freshking

```
- (NSMutableArray *) checkForWords:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSMutableArray *words = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[textField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy]];
    NSMutableArray *matches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //NSLog(@"words: %@",words);

    for (NSString *word in words) {
        NSString *firstCharacter = [word substringToIndex:1];
        if (![firstCharacter isEqual:@"#"] && ![firstCharacter isEqual:@"@"]) {
            [matches addObject:word];
        }
    }

    return matches;
}
```